# What is known about the sum $\sum\frac1{p^p}$ of reciprocals of primes raised to themselves?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, rationality-testing

Consider the following series:

$$\sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\frac{1}{p^p}$$

where $\mathcal{P}$ is the set of all prime numbers: $\mathcal{P}=\{2,3,5,7,11,13,\ldots\}$. My question is:

> Is this a known series? In case it is, what is it's name in literature?

With a simple comparison, we conclude that it is convergent and:

$$0\leq \frac{1}{p^p}\leq \frac{1}{p^2}\Rightarrow 0\leq\sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\frac{1}{p^p}\leq\sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\frac{1}{p^2}<\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1\approx 0.64493$$

and for $p\in\{2,3,5,7,11,13\}=\mathcal{P}_{13}$ my calculator outputed:

$$\sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}_{13}}\frac{1}{p^p}\approx 0.287358251$$

But what else can we say about it? Is it a rational number? In case it isn't rational, is it algebraic (and if it is what can we say about the minimal polynomial)?

Comment: Yes, it is known - see [A094289](http://oeis.org/A094289)

Comment: Does anyone know if $\sum_{p \in P} \frac{1}{p}$ converges? That could be an interesting problem.

Comment: @GiantTortoise1729, it diverges - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes

Comment: @Larara Do you have any more specific questions? If not, I think the oeis reference would suffice as an answer, because the constant doesn't seem to have a name. (Googling "A094289 prime" does not give anything interesting.)

Comment: @GiantTortoise1729 Here is a really interesting problem. The natural numbers $n$ and $n+2$ are called _twin primes_ if they are both primes (_e.g._, 3 and 5, 11 and 13, 137 and 139). It is known that the sum of the reciprocals of twin primes does converge. However, it is not known whether it is because there are only finitely many of them or because there are infinitely many of them but they are “rare.” This has been an [open problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) for more than 150 years!

Comment: @triple_sec Oh, wow, that is interesting. Thank you!

Comment: @barto, I edited the question.

Comment: A comment on this question contains a link to a paper (http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.4299) which proves the irrationality of $\sum\frac1{p!}$; it may give inspiration to prove the irrationality of $\sum\frac1{p^p}$: [Sum of reciprocals of factorials of primes $\sum\frac1{p!}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548589)