# Value of $\sum 1/p^p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

A very simple question, but I can't seem to find anything relating to it :

Is there any research, are there any results that have focused on or given insight on

### $\sum 1/p^p$, ${p \in \mathbb P}$ ?

A very basic series, converges extremely fast, its value is around .29. What more can there be said about it ?

From what little I know about more advanced number theory, similar sequences (I can think of a few similar ones that I can't find any relevant research or results about) can be very non-trivial to compute or to analyse.

Comment: The first digits are at the [Prime pages](http://primes.utm.edu/curios/page.php?number_id=3733) and appear too [here](http://www.peeranswer.com/question/55c214b1f18084506c5ef828) and [here](http://math.troplet.com/question/what-is-known-about-the-sum-sum-frac1-p-p-of-reciprocals-of-primes-raised-to-themselves-1344000.html) and the question was asked earlier at [SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1344000).

Comment: Thank you ! I'm surprised I didn't find that topic when searching for it.

Comment: How can we search "1/p^p" here?  I don't know.

Comment: @GEdgar and spliblib: I searched the numerical value using google (reducing progressively the number of digits since only exact matches will return results).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [OEIS A094289](http://oeis.org/A094289), where they have no information except computations of the value.  This suggests the answer "no" to the question "is there any research ..."

Comment: Ah, I guess that answers it, then. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

*What more can there be said about it ?*

Essentially nothing. Related series are

- [Sophomore's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream) $\displaystyle C_s=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^n}$.
- [Prime zeta values](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html) $\displaystyle P(k)=\sum_{p\in\mathbb P}\frac{1}{p^k}$, with $k\in\mathbb N_{\ge 2}$.

No closed form expressions for these constants are known so far.

Comment: I am not asking specifically for closed form expressions. I am aware of the fact that similar expressions have no closed forms.

What I meant is that I have found nothing whatsoever relating to the sequence I mentioned, whereas the Sophomore series has a couple of things that can be said about it (the formula in the wikipedia page, links to Stirling's formula), and the prime zeta series seems to have been extensively studied.

Comment: @spliblib This is why I give the link to prime zeta function. It seems to me to be the simplest reasonable relative of your series.

Answer (score 1):

it may not be elegant but as an idea $\sum = \sum_{n=1}^{n=5}1/{p^p} + \sum_{n=6}1/{p^p}$ 
and as per [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) leverage approximation / boundaries

$\log{n} + \log{\log{n}} - 1 < \frac{p_n}{n} < \log{n} + \log{\log{n}}$  for $n \geq 6$

and then look at convergence of $\sum_{n=6}$

Answer (score 1):

Other than its rational approximation

$$
\frac{5226294}{18187381},
$$

not much is known about this constant. In particular, its irrationality/transcendentality seems to be out of reach with current technology. However, it can be related to similar constants, such as:

- The prime zeta function:
  $$
  P(k)=\sum_{p\in\mathbb P}\frac{1}{p^k}, \ \ Re(k)>1,
  $$
- $n$-ary representations of the Prime Constant:
  $$
  f(k)=\sum_{p\in\mathbb P}\frac{1}{k^p},
  $$

(noting that $f(2)$ is the Prime Constant $\rho=0.414682509\ldots$),

- Sophomore's constant:

$$
C_s=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^n}.
$$

As pointed out by others, there is more information on the OEIS website ([A094289](http://oeis.org/A094289)).