# Is the series: $\frac{\pi}{p_{1}!}+\frac{\pi}{p_{2}!}+...+\frac{\pi}{p_{n}!}$ convergent or divergent, where $p_n$ is the $n$-th odd prime?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, transcendental-numbers

> Is the series: $$\frac{\pi}{p_{1}!}+\frac{\pi}{p_{2}!}+...+\frac{\pi}{p_{n}!}$$ convergent or divergent, where $p_n$ is the $n$th odd prime?
>
> And also why it is (the partial sums) transcendental?

**Note**: I've just started studying about a series being convergent or divergent. I know the definition of convergent/divergent series, but, I somewhat failed to understand the relation of "**limit**" of a series.

Regards

Comment: When you say "why is it transcendental", what do you mean by "it"?  A series isn't a number and can't be transcendental or otherwise, so you are either referring to each partial sum, or the limit of the series.  Which is it?

Comment: If you just begin to learn about convergence, then you probably do not want to attempt to do series with primes right away.

Comment: I meant that the partial sum of this series is a transcendental number. @ErickWong

Comment: Yeah! I shouldn't, but I have a tendency to play with prime numbers in every case, I'm just obsessed and fascinated with primes. @GEdgar

Comment: I know this is not part of the question, but what techniques could be used to calculate this series?

Comment: What the hell is "the partial sum of this series"? a series is, by definition, the sequence of partial sums associated to another given sequence. Please be more careful in your writing.

Comment: This might be of use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548589/sum-of-reciprocals-of-primes-factorial-sum-p-textprime-frac1p

Comment: Sorry for the lack of formal understanding/definition regarding series and sequences on my part, as I mentioned that I'm new on this subject. By the way, I was simply trying to say that the sum of the series is a number, and that number is a transcendental one. @YoTengoUnLCD

Comment: The partial sums are trancendental since we have $S_n = \pi\left(1/2! + 1/3! + \ldots + 1/p_n!\right) = \pi\times Q$ where $Q$ is a rational number (since a finite sum of rationals is rational) and a trancendental number times a rational number is a trancendental number.

Comment: Is $\pi$ primepi, or the $\pi$ that is $=3.1415...$?

Answer (score 2):

The "$k$th odd prime" part is there to throw you off. Show ${\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {\pi \over k!}}$ converges using one of your techniques (they all work for this), then the comparison test will show your series converges.

Transcendentalness is a lot harder... I'd try to just understand convergence first.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\pi}{p_n!}= \pi \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p_n!}$$

It is clear, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p_n!}<\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}$$ converges (to $e$) therefore $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p_n!}$$

converges. Multiplying it by $\pi$ will still yield convergence.

I don't know if it's transcendental or not, I have nothing to say on that matter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the partial sums are trancendental. The partial sums can be written

$$S_n = \pi\left(\frac{1}{p_1!} + \ldots + \frac{1}{p_n!}\right) = \pi Q$$

where $Q$ is rational since a finite sum of rationals is rational. Now [we know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31798/prove-that-pi-is-a-transcendental-number) that $\pi$ is trancendental and a product of a rational and a trancendental number is trancendental. The proof of this is given below.

---

> If $\alpha$ is transendental and $r$ rational then $\beta = r\alpha$ is trancendental.

Proof: Assume that $\beta = r\alpha$ is algebraic. This means that there exists a polynomial $f(x) = a_m x^m + \ldots +a_1 x + a_0$ with rational coefficients $a_i$ such that $f(\beta) = 0$. But then $g(x) = f(x\beta/\alpha) = [a_m r^m] x^m + \ldots +[a_1 r]x + a_0$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients that has $\alpha$ as a root. This contradics $\alpha$ being trancendental and $\beta$ must therefore also be trancendental.