# Is there a name for this number?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, notation

> Is there a name for the number $$\sum_{p\ prime} \frac{1}{p!}=0.6751984379111143419005616\cdots$$ ?

I also wonder whether this number has been studied and in particular , whether it is known whether the number is rational, algebraic irrational or transcendental.

Comment: See this....http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548589/sum-of-reciprocals-of-primes-factorial-sum-p-textprime-frac1p/548600

Comment: I believe that it is A100124, as a Sloane's sequence, see if it is related in the Online Encyclopedia of integer sequences.

Comment: What about $e'$ ?

Comment: I believe this sum is less than $e$ which can be easily seen by its power series expansion

Comment: @DietrichBurde Seems that nothing special is known about the number. Impressing however that the symbolic calculator idendified the decimal expansion to be that sum! So, I think, I can well accept the duplicate ...

Comment: We "know" it is transcendental because it has no reason to be anything else, but proving that is usually hard.

Comment: @RossMillikan I had some hope that it has been solved, but it seems to be not the case.